# Strange behavior UITableView using viewWithTag

Tags: objective-c, xcode, uitableview

I have a UILabel in my tableview and I set the tag manually to 1

I have this code and it works good when I run the app. I do scroll down and works, the names are filled correctly.

But when I click in the cell and scroll down again sometimes the label from the cell has an error as follows:

**unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x7fc01d74a710**  <- this is my label and I printed the description of error:

Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: '-[Mediprecios.RotatedView setText:]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x7f8d9073f4f0'
  And crashes in method cellForRowAtIndexPath in labelName.text = name;

```
po 0x7fc01d74b370
<Mediprecios.RotatedView: 0x7fc01d74b370; frame = (0 100; 345 100); alpha = 0; tag = 1; layer = <CALayer: 0x600000827dc0>>

- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {
    FoldingCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:@"cell"];

   UILabel *labelName = [cell viewWithTag:1];
   NSString *name = [displayItems objectForKey:@"Name"];
   labelName.text = name;

   return cell;
}

- (void) tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {

   FoldingCell *cell = [tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:indexPath];

   if (cell.isAnimating) {
       return;
   }

   double duration = 0;
   NSNumber *height = [self.cellHeights objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
   bool cellIsCollapsed = height.floatValue == self.kCloseCellHeight;
   if (cellIsCollapsed) {
        [self.cellHeights setObject:[NSNumber numberWithFloat:self.kOpenCellHeight] atIndexedSubscript:indexPath.row];

    [cell unfold:YES animated:YES completion:nil];
    duration = 0.5;

} else {
    [self.cellHeights setObject:[NSNumber numberWithFloat:self.kCloseCellHeight] atIndexedSubscript:indexPath.row];
    //[cell selectedAnimation:false animated:true completion: nil];
    [cell unfold:NO animated:YES completion:nil];
    duration = 0.8;
}

[UIView animateWithDuration:duration delay:0 options:0 animations:^{
    [tableView beginUpdates];
    [

tableView endUpdates];
    } completion:nil];

}
```

PD: I use this library https://github.com/Ramotion/folding-cell

Comment: Please show the complete error message. And point out the exact line of code causing the error.

Comment: Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: '-[Mediprecios.RotatedView setText:]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x7f8d9073f4f0'
  And crashes in method cellForRowAtIndexPath in labelName.text = name;

Comment: Instead of dealing with tags, why not provide a read-only access to the `labelName` property of your `FoldingCell` class, much like `textLabel` is provided in `UITableViewCell`.

Comment: And [edit] your question with the error. Details belong in the question, not in comments.

Comment: Its a bug from Xcode, only I changed the tag number from other like 1001 and works perfectly.

Comment: That's not an Xcode bug. That simply means there was another view with a tag of 1. This is why using tags is a bad design choice.

Comment: No, because I chequed all views and subviews and doesn't have a tag 1, Also I run the app all the labels showns well (labelName.text) the app works fine,  but when I click in someone cell and scroll down, sometimes the app crashes

Comment: And for this particular case I cant Subclass a FoldingCell because is programmed in SWIFT this is the only way to implement this functionality. Please check out this link: github.com/Ramotion/folding-cell

Comment: It's not a bug in Xcode. The implementation of FoldingCell does all kinds of things with tags. See for yourself at https://github.com/Ramotion/folding-cell/blob/master/FoldingCell/FoldingCell/FoldingCell.swift. Your own use of using tag `1` conflicts with the tags used in the FoldingCell class. It started working when you changed to a tag value that didn't conflict.

Comment: ok thanks I take care of that

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Look at the error `[Mediprecios.RotatedView setText:]` Your code is actually trying to call setText method on a view rather than on label.
`UILabel *labelName = [cell viewWithTag:1];` My guess is your cell has any `UIView` with tag 1 not `UILabel`.
Hence `labelName.text = name;` this line actually tries to set text on a `UIView` as `labelName` is a `UIView`.

Try changing the tag to a big random number like 35432 and check.

Above solution is a temporary work around to get rid of the error. Good practice will be to create your own implementation of `FoldingCell` by subclassing it and connect the `IBOutlet` of your label to the cell class and access it.

Comment: Woow this is a bug from Xcode!!! only I changed the tag number to another big number like 1001,1002 and works perfectly. Thanks for your advice. Also I cant create a implementation of Folding Cell because I use this framework https://github.com/Ramotion/folding-cell in Swift.

Comment: No, its not the bug from Xcode, there must be some view in `FoldingCell` with tag 1.

Comment: And You can always subclass the `FoldingCell` class and create your own Cell class to have this functionality in more elegant manner.

Comment: No, because I chequed all views and subviews and doesn't have a tag 1, Also I run the app all the labels showns well (labelName.text) the app works fine,  but when I click in someone cell and scroll down, sometimes the app crashes

Comment: And for this particular case I cant Subclass a FoldingCell because is programmed in SWIFT this is the only way to implement this functionality. Please check out this link: https://github.com/Ramotion/folding-cell